# play audio without user interact jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, audio

i'm building a dashboard in which user get notified(by sound) for new orders ,  so i want audio to play without letting user click any button 
 noticed this problem :
"play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first" . 
tried answers from these posts but non of them worked same problem 
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450033/playing-sound-notifications-using-javascript)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use/52821721#52821721)
[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388258/what-constitues-user-gesture)
[link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492358/how-to-trigger-click-event-manually/45492408)
[link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356956/playing-audio-after-the-page-loads-in-html/14357365)

my google Chrome  Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

code:

HTML

```
<div><audio src="../audio/message.mp3" id="mainaudio"></audio>
<button id="btn" hidden> clicked automatically</button></div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#btn').click(function(){document.getElementById("mainaudio").play();});
setInterval(function(){

var oldreq=$("[name='show-order[]'] span").html();
var oldsugg=$("[name='show-sugg[]'] span ").html();

$.ajax({
        url:"../include/uid.php",
        type:"post",
        data:"method=reloadNav&oldOrder="+oldreq+"&oldSug="+oldsugg,
        success:function(data){
            var js=$.parseJSON(data);
            if(js.notify == 1){
                $("#btn").click();
            }
            $("[name='show-order[]'] span").html(js.order);
            $("[name='show-sugg[]'] span").html(js.sug) ;  
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("ajax error");
        }
    })


},5000);
```

Comment: Did you find solution @Ruaa Elias?

Comment: No @KnowledgeSeeker

Answer (score 0):

You can start playing music a few seconds after loading the page

```
$(window).on( "click", function() { //prevent 'no interact error'
    setTimeout(function() { // start play after 5 sec
        var el = document.getElementById("mainaudio");
        if(el.paused){ //check if music dont play now
            el.play();
        }
        else{
            console.log('already playing!');
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```